# MSYS2 does not source .profile

Tags: mingw, msys, bash, mintty, msys2

Using MSYS2, if I run `msys2_shell.bat`, `mintty` opens a bash login shell, but  `~/.profile` does not get sourced.

Anyway if I run  `/bin/bash --login` inside `mintty`, `~/.profile` get sourced. Why?

The same happens if I run `path\to\msys64\bin\bash.exe --login` via Windows prompt instead of `msys2_shell.bat`.

PS: I tried also with `.bash_profile`.

Comment: There is a difference between launching a shell with login and not. This is why you need the --login

Comment: the question is not about what a login shell is, but why `.profile` is not sourced.

Comment: Because you are not entering a 'login' shell.. This is a feature and the difference between a 'login' shell and not.

Comment: @xxcezz: Why did you say say that I am not in a login shell? `msys2_shell.bat` opens a login shell.

Comment: I misunderstood the issue. Sorry. Can you update msys2_shell.bat to create a login shell?

Comment: @xxcezz: Again? `msys2_shell.bat` does open a login shell!

Comment: Then I do not understand. You said that when you open it with --login it does source the profile.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55257/discussion-between-antonio-and-xxcezz).

Comment: @antonio - I have the same issue. I am using `mingw64_shell.bat` which starts mintty/bash with `start %WD%mintty -i /msys2.ico /usr/bin/bash --login %*`. I added some logging to `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.profile`.  with `bash --login`, only `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` are executed/sourced.  Whereas with cygwin, `~/.bash_profile` is sourced with `bash --login`.  It seems this is a bug with `msys2`.  See http://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/97/

Comment: @antonio - I figured out solution... The `/etc/fstab` needs to be edited... see my answer below.

Comment: Having the same issue, but neither of the answers below work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Disabling (renaming) system wide `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile` is sourced.

After investigating `/etc/profile` I saw that, keeping it but commenting the function `profile_d ()`  `~/.profile` is sourced. This function runs the scripts in `/etc/profile.d/`.

Disabling them individually I realized that the culprit is `/etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh`.

It reads:

```
# Check for interactive bash and that we haven't already been sourced.
[ -z "$BASH_VERSION" -o -z "$PS1" -o -n "$BASH_COMPLETION_COMPAT_DIR" ] && return

# Check for recent enough version of bash.
bash=${BASH_VERSION%.*}; bmajor=${bash%.*}; bminor=${bash#*.}
if [ $bmajor -gt 4 ] || [ $bmajor -eq 4 -a $bminor -ge 1 ]; then
    [ -r "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/bash_completion" ] && \
        . "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/bash_completion"
    if shopt -q progcomp && [ -r /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
        # Source completion code.
        . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
    fi
fi
unset bash bmajor bminor
```

The first line explains why when running the subshell (the second time) things work: environment variables are already set, so the script returns.

The problem is that `bash_completion.sh` runs `/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion`, which is really huge and it is difficult to grasp the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue.

> I figured it out with the help of Dan in this ticket's comment thread: https://sourceforge.net/p/msys2/tickets/97

The solution is to edit the `/etc/fstab`

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# For a description of the file format, see the Users Guide
# http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#mount-table

# DO NOT REMOVE NEXT LINE. It remove cygdrive prefix from path
none / cygdrive binary,posix=0,noacl,user 0 0

d:/Users/dparker /home/dparker ntfs binary,posix=0,user 0 0
```

Notice the last line is necessary to mount your home dir... I am not sure why you need to explicitly do this in `/etc/fstab` because it seems to mount it without it being there... but maybe it wasn't mounting it *properly*?

Hope this works for you like it did for me.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work properly if the path has spaces in it, which many Windows user dirs do. Eg. `c:/Users/user\040name /home/user\040name ntfs ...`. I end up getting part of the "ntfs" in the mounted directory, ie `/home/user name nt`